# Postgres Wire Protocol NoticeResponse message not matching documentation

Tags: postgresql

Using postgres version 10.8 client from an EC2 instance using a 11.1 postgres server in an RDS instance.

psql (10.8 (Ubuntu 10.8-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 11.1).

According to:
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/protocol-message-formats.html
The format for the NoticeResponse message is:

NoticeResponse (B)
Byte1('N') [identifying the message as a NoticeResponse message]

Int32 [Length of message contents in bytes, including self]

Followed by a sequence of 1-byte fields -- indicating a message type -- and then a null-terminated string. The sequence itself is then null terminated.

So, a sample message might look like:
*'N' [4-bytes to indicate message length] 'S' 'W' 'A' 'R' 'N' 'I' 'N' 'G' \0 'C' '0' '3' '0' '0' '0' \0 'M' 'U' 'N' 'H' 'A' 'P' 'P' 'Y' ' ' 'Q' 'U' 'E' 'R' 'Y' \0 \0*

Here, the "S" before "WARNING" indicates a severity-type message, the "C" indicates a SQL State (in this case, 03000), the "M" before "UNHAPPY QUERY" indicates the primary message.

What I am seeing instead is:
*'N' [4 bytes indicating 80 byte message] \0 \3\ \0 \0 'u''s''e''r'\0'[redacted username] \0 'd''a''t''a''b''a''s''e'\0[redacted name]\0'a''p''p''l''i''c''a''t''i''o''n''_''n''a''m''e'\0'p''s''q''l''c''l''i''e''n''t''_''e''n''c''o''d''i''n''g'\0'U''T''F''8'\0\0*

(The redactions are put in there by me -- the actual message contains the username and schema name I am connecting to).
In other words, it appears as key-value pairs terminated by a final null character, and with the addition of the mysterious sequence \0\3\0\0 near the beginning.

So here is the question:
**Is there documentation that I am missing? Was there a change in server version 11.1 on RDS for how it performs the wire protocol?**

**EDIT: I discovered the problem.**

The 'N' is actually a response to an SSLRequest from the server -- indicating that SSL communication is not supported. The following contents were from the client indicating a startup message, and the 0300 was 4 bytes indicating that wire version 3.00 is being selected.

Since the channel I was listening on was listening to both the client and server messages, and I got confused by the apparently combined message.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask this sort of question on the postgresql mailing lists. The developers will be the best people to advise you.

Comment: For me, the NoticeResponse looks just like you expect it should. What command exactly did you run to get a NoticeResponse like that?